# Request Data from CoreData in Today Extension

Tags: ios, core-data

i have an app with ios 8, swift and CoreData.
all works fine :)

now i would like to add an today extion - this is my first time to work with today extions. i very proud to say, that i already can set in my app an NSUserdafault value and show it on my today extension :)

but now i would like to go a step forward.
in my app i have a CoreData Entiny LM_ITEMS with an Attribute "Hersteller"

how can i list up all data of LM_ITEMS in my today extension?
Thank you :)

in my app i do it like this way:

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var LM = [LM_ITEMS]()

func DatenAbrufen() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LM_ITEMS")
    if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [LM_ITEMS] {
        LM = fetchResults
    }
}
```

But this doesnt work in today extension ...

Answer (score 0):

You should better create a core data stack singleton object and include it in both targets, your app's target and extension target.

Comment: my app and the widget use the same App Group in the target capabilities. how can i place the core data in the shared container. where can i find this container. and what is a core data stack singleton object and why i should to use this?

Comment: You need to use the NSFileManager's 'containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier' method to access the shared container and create the database there. About the singleton object, i recommend that because this way you can reuse the object and you can use it in your application target and also in the extension target.

Comment: ok thx. is there an simple example code available for singleton object?

Comment: You can check this article, it explains singletons well: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: Works the same way :) here is an example: https://gist.github.com/mattdonnelly/0212206ffe7e91dcbdf2

Comment: i dont understand how this code can request data of my coredata oO

Comment: You can move the core data stack (NSManagedObjectModel, NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and NSManagedObjectContext) and all the core data related methods into the singleton object then you can add your code to request data or whatever you want.
If you don't know what to do with the singleton i recommend you to read about it, here is a good article: http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1

Comment: sry, but i need a real example. is ik okay for you, to create for me a raal example for how i can load all data out of my coredata and show the result in my app and in my today extension as a singleton object. if i see the solution i unerstand it better as a general tutorial. thank you for help

Comment: You just need to move the Core Data related code that is created automatically for you, from AppDelegate to the Singleton object and, instead of accessing the NSManagedObjectContext through the AppDelegate, you will do that using your singleton object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86632/discussion-between-ghost108-and-lucian-boboc).

Answer (score 0):

What @Lucian said is correct and can become very useful if you want to add other targets.

However if you want access the same database of your main app you have to make both the app and the widget use the same App Group in the target capabilities and place your core data database in the shared container.